# Distribute Software Tokens using RSA SecurID API/SDK for JAVA

Tags: java, api, securid

I'm developing a system to assign the next available software token for a user, issue and distribute it using RSA Authentication Manager 7.1 Developer's Guide and accordingly this JAVA API reference.

The problem is that some points are unclear for me regarding sub types of software token generated and file format to export.

Below is the source code that I have produced and my doubts rely on comments.

```
private void assignNextAvailableTokenToUser(String userGuid, String admGuid)
        throws CommandException, IOException {
        GetNextAvailableTokenCommand cmd = new GetNextAvailableTokenCommand();

        try {
            cmd.execute();  
        } catch (DataNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: No tokens available");
            return;
        }

        String[] tokens = new String[] { cmd.getToken().getId() };
        // how can I guarantee that only software tokens will be assign to the user ???
        LinkTokensWithPrincipalCommand cmd2 = new LinkTokensWithPrincipalCommand(tokens, userGuid);
        cmd2.execute();
        System.out.println("Assigned next available SecurID token to user " + USER_NAME);

        IssueSoftwareTokensCommand issueCmd = new IssueSoftwareTokensCommand();

        DistributeSoftTokenRequest  disToken = new DistributeSoftTokenRequest();

        SoftTokenDeviceInfoDTO  softwareTokenDeviceDTO = new SoftTokenDeviceInfoDTO();

        softwareTokenDeviceDTO.setAlgorithm(SoftTokenDeviceInfoDTO.ST_FILE_FORMAT_SDTID3);
        softwareTokenDeviceDTO.setMaxTokensPerFile(SoftTokenDeviceInfoDTO.ST_MAX_PER_FILE_UNLIMITED);        
        softwareTokenDeviceDTO.setFileFormat(SoftTokenDeviceInfoDTO.ST_FILE_FORMAT_SDTID3);
        // how to link the information above with IssueSoftwareTokensCommand ??

        String[] tokensGuid = new String[]{cmd.getToken().getId()};

        disToken.setTokenGuids(tokensGuid);
        disToken.setProtectedMethod(DistributeSoftTokenRequest.ST_PROTECTED_BY_PASSWORD);
        disToken.setPassword("xpto");
        disToken.setCopyProtected(true);
        disToken.setDeviceType("?????????"); //how to fill this parameter for android or ios ??        
        disToken.setDeviceTypePluginModuleName("???????"); //how to fill this parameter for android or ios ?? 
        disToken.setOutputMethod(DistributeSoftTokenRequest.ST_OUTPUT_ONE_PER_FILE);
        disToken.setRegenerateSeed(true);        
        disToken.setPinAdded(true);
        disToken.setOtpAlgorithm(DistributeSoftTokenRequest.OTPAlgorithm.EVENT);
        disToken.setOtpInterval(DistributeSoftTokenRequest.OTPInterval.SIXTY_SECONDS);
        disToken.setOtpLength(DistributeSoftTokenRequest.OTPLength.SIX_DIGITS);

        issueCmd.setRequest(disToken);

        ConnectionFactory.executeCommand(admGuid, issueCmd);

        String fileName = issueCmd.getFileId();

        GetSoftwareTokenFileCommand getSoftwareTokenFileCommand = new GetSoftwareTokenFileCommand(fileName);

        getSoftwareTokenFileCommand.execute();

        byte[] fileContent = getSoftwareTokenFileCommand.getFileContent();

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\tokens\\" + fileName);
        try {
            stream.write(fileContent);
        } finally {
            stream.close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use AM 8.1SP1 or AM 8.2 It has in-build to distribute the token either url based or file based.